# Connect with Asp.Net and Flex using remote objects

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex

Can any one tell me how can I connect .net and flex using remote objects? Actually till now I know how can flex and jsp connects with HTTP services, but now I need to connect with .net. 
So how can I retrieve the values from .net(backend) and display it in frontend(flex)? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[FlourineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) is a really great project that approaches this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at[WebORB for .NET](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html)